# my router work on django rest frame work 1.11 but this code not working in django rest frame work 2

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
Trip_router.register(r'places', views.PlaceViewSet, base_name='trips-places')\
.register(r'people', views.PersonInPlaceViewSet, base_name='trips-places-people')
```

this is my error

```
Trip_router.register(r'places', views.PlaceViewSet, base_name='trips-places')\
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'register'

Comment: Looks like you are calling Trip_router.register().register(). Are you sure that is correct? I would guess that .register() returns None, raising this error. Seems the correct thing would be doing:
```Trip_router.register(...)
Trip_router.register(...)```

Comment: i need to register child from  url to create selection like this  /api/places/1/people to select people of one place  this code work on django 1.11

Comment: but now this import making error from  rest_framework_extensions.routers import ExtendedSimpleRouter